# Does Perl have something similar to the Django automatic administrator interface?

Tags: django, web-services, perl, web-applications

I was wondering if there's a glue module to link the likes of DBIx::Class, Mojo et al. together and automatically generate forms, schema etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is:

- [`DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader`](http://search.cpan.org/~rkitover/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader-0.07033/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader.pm) - which generates your DBIC models - it can handle DB FK constraints to generate the relationships between them too, but I like to use it just for generating columns
- [`HTML::FormHandler`](http://search.cpan.org/~gshank/HTML-FormHandler-0.40016/lib/HTML/FormHandler.pm) and [`HTML::FormHandler::Generator::DBIC`](http://search.cpan.org/~gshank/HTML-FormHandler-0.40016/lib/HTML/FormHandler.pm) that I like to use for form generation/handling

Do a [duckduckgo search for perl CRUD](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=perl%20crud) and choose a solution from there if you want something fast.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Catalyst has [AutoCRUD](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aAutoCRUD) which is pretty excellent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.